# Как средствами JS сформировать GUID по маске?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Стоит задача средствами ***JavaScript*** сформировать **GUID** (статистически уникальный 128-битный идентификатор) по маске **xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx** например *8d7385ad-b837-4953-814e-z6789c27c631*.

Если у кого есть готовое решение, поделитесь, пожалуйста...

Comment: Вам нужен _настоящий_ GUID, или случайное число, которое _выглядит_ как GUID?

Comment: Для "случайного" значения есть [rfc](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4122).

Comment: Со случайным то все просто  

    function getGUID() {
        var guid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
            var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
             return v.toString(16);
        });     
        return guid;
    }

Так что меня интересует, как Вы выразились *настоящий GUID*...  
Или приближенный к нему...

Comment: Приближенных не бывает - либо настоящий, либо "на JavaScript".

Comment: Я не видел как получить нормальный GUID в JavaScript...  
Потому и задаю вопрос...   
Может кто писал или находил алгоритм генерации GUID на JavaScript или просто функцию получения GUID...  

Алгоритм генерации случайного GUID конечно неплохо, но желательно получить *правильный*...

Comment: Я конечно не пробовал, но возможно можно через ActiveX...  
Хотя, это вариант больше для IE...

Comment: @ReinRaus: вот, кстати, инсайдерская статья: [GUIDs are designed to be unique, not random](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/23/10309199.aspx). Заменяет некоторую часть статьи по вашей ссылке.

Comment: @ReinRaus, нашел не на стэке, спасибо что поправили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@t1nk](/users/7575/t1nk)](/users/7575/t1nk), как-то непонятно. Вроде и со стэка скопировали, но вроде и не так как там. Копируйте без ошибок в следующий раз:

```
'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
});
```

В таком виде результат будет соответствовать версии `The randomly or pseudo-randomly generated version`
По ссылке ниже чей-то труд по дизассемблированию микрософтовой генерации GUID, если так сильно хочется правильный GUID- реализуйте на JavaScript
http://www.gotdotnet.ru/blogs/denish/1965/